# Enlarging a structure

Tags: scale

I'm having a structure which I would need to enlarge into the arrow directions by 5.5 mm each. I tried to set the length of specific edges, but this gets weird quickly.

The inner edges would need to be changed from 32.5 mm to 38 mm, the outer from 36.5 to 42.

Does anybody have a hint, how to achieve this?

TIA

[image]

Comment: to know the size of a selection you have the MeasureIt addon, to change the size of a selection you have the Edit Mesh Tool addon, maybe look into these 2?

Comment: Yes, did that already. I soon fu..d up the design entirely

Comment: Basically I would just think I would have to copy a 5.5 mm stripe out of the existing and paste it into. On both sides. Or maybe loop cut and extrude or so...

Comment: I don't get the problem, ( why not grab all the verts in the thickness on the right side and GX 5.5mm, followed by all the verts in the thickness on the near side, and GY 5.5mm ? )

Comment: @Robin. Thanks a lot. Yes, for one it is simple, for a beginner it is the hell on earth :) Thanks worked.

Comment: @decades :) The hell doesn't last long, and then you should find you can model faster than in some applications with more complex interfaces you have to hunt through, IMO.